# Convert BytesWritable type to InputStream in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, inputstream, hdfs

Could anybody tell the best way to convert BytesWritable type to InputStream in Hadoop (in map phase)? I have appropriate method that use InputStream type and i want use it in my MR program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the below code you can see how byte array is converted to Input Stream. Now to get the byte array you can use [BytesWritable get bytes](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/BytesWritable.html#getBytes%28%29)  method to get the byte array. And after getting the byte array you can use the above code logic in mapper to get the input stream.I hope that answers your query. So I think this can be one of the best approach which I can suggest.

Hi I think you can check the following code:-

```
public class ByteArrToInputStream {

public static void main(String a[]){

    String str = "converting to input stream";
    byte[] content = str.getBytes();
    int size = content.length;
    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] b = new byte[size];
    try {
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
        is.read(b);
        System.out.println("Data Recovered: "+new String(b));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            if(is != null) is.close();
        } catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }

}
```

}